# Is there anything like "companyID" when forming campaign url for store apps?

Tags: uwp

I found a msdn [reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b774a8ef-ad4a-4c51-8ef0-26577c2ce164/how-to-send-the-campaign-id-when-forming-store-protocol-urls?forum=wpdevelop) useful, for forming custom campaign url to get statistics of which app or campaign helped me a lot to install a particular app, say its id = abc. So I should form that url as:

```
ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=abc?cid=newpromotion
```

But, in that reply, it is mentioned that, I have to find the "companyID of the source app", I have searched a lot, but it is not found in any documentation of msdn. Is there any like  "companyID of the source app"?
Is it different from Store Id & custom_campaign_id ? If so, please show me the documentation mentioned in microsoft site.

Comment: Please check above msdn case latest update, our team has provide related [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-a-custom-app-promotion-campaign#programmatically-retrieve-the-custom-campaign-id-for-an-app).

Comment: Sorry. There is only campaign id. No CompanyID. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no such `CompanyID`,  it should be campaign id.